# bind radiobutton in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
Radio Button checked item should be true based on entry.isalbum value. Below is my View code..    

@foreach(abc.Models.ddt entry in entrydetails)
        {    
    @if(entry.isAlbum=="Album")
        {
        <input type="radio" id="c" name="isAlbum" checked="checked" value="Album" />

         <label style="margin-right:10px" for="c"><span></span>Album</label>
            }

         <input type="radio" id="c1" name="isAlbum"  value="Movies" />

         <label style="margin-right:10px" for="c1"><span></span>Movies</label>

         <input type="radio" id="c2"  name="isAlbum" value="Single" />

         <label style="margin-right:10px" for="c2"><span></span>Single</label>

        </div>
    }
    }
```

foreach loop contain value stroed in database corresponding to Album, Movies or Single.
        radio button checked should be true based on entry.isAlbum vale. How can we do this, please help to us? I have three radiobutton mention in above code. Radio Button checked will be true based on entry.Isalbum vale. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" id="c" name="isAlbum" @if(entry.isAlbum=="Album"){<text>checked="checked"</text>} value="Album" />

<input type="radio" id="c1" name="isAlbum" @if(entry.isAlbum=="Movies"){<text>checked="checked"</text>} value="Movies" />

<input type="radio" id="c2" name="isAlbum" @if(entry.isAlbum=="Single"){<text>checked="checked"</text>} value="Single" />
```